# Having difficulty in generating a local server in an already existing web project using Jekyll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I just downloaded a blog model in github and want to do some modification myself. so I ran

```
$ jekyll build
```

but faild to generate the local server, the error message is listed below:

```
mywebsite git:(gh-pages) ✗ jekyll build
Configuration file: /Users/phoenix/Documents/script/mywebsite/_config.yml
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- jekyll-paginate (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `block in require_gems'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:27:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:27:in `require_gems'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:19:in `conscientious_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:49:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/bin/jekyll:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

but when I ran 
$ jekyll new newsite and jekyll server, it works just fine. 
My os is OS X 10.11, Jykell 3.0.1, can anyone tell my how to generate a local server in an already exists directory?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution myself. I followed the instructions from this site:
http://www.blogways.net/blog/2013/04/08/install-jekyll-on-mac.html
for those who can't read Chinese, I run the following commands in terminal:

```
$export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH

$gem install jekyll rdiscount RedCloth

$gem install github-pages
```

now it works. But I am still not sure what exactly went wrong, I guess it was that I missed some module for Markdown or it was the ruby path issue..